# how to use filter in grails

Tags: grails, filter

I have a filter that i want to filter every action except ONE that brings me to login page.

If i filter all pages with some condition then even the LOGIN page too get filtered and so it stuck in infinte loop as condition not fulfilled (User not Logged IN).
**session.getAttribute("CurrentEmployeeIds")** it tell whether user is logged in or not

My filter here:

```
class LoginFilters {

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'dashboard', action:'*') {
            before = {
                if (session.getAttribute("CurrentEmployeeIds")==null) {
                    redirect(controller:"site",action:"index")
                    return false
                }
            }
            after = { Map model ->

            }
            afterView = { Exception e ->

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to filter in such a way that it don't filter `controller:"site",action:"index"` this url and filter everything else.

 thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get the action and controller name by `actionName` and `controllerName`, just do a check on, simple `if` statement. you can return `true` for that specific action.

Comment: How is this related to Struts 2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can **invert** filter rule, like:

```
def filters = {
    allExceptIndex(controller:"site",action:"index",invert:true) {
        before = {
        }
        after = { Map model ->
        }
        afterView = { Exception e ->
        }
    }
}
```

See docs [http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters](https://web.archive.org/web/20130801072309/http://grails.org:80/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters)